# spring boot multi module maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

I tried to create a multi module spring boot, I used this methode :

- create a root project with Spring Initializr, and sub modules with a simple project maven.

this the architecture :

Root project (packaging as POM, contain spring-boot-starter-parent, and I removed the spring-boot-maven-plugin from the pom)

1. project-application (packaging as JAR)
2. project-domain (packaging as JAR)
3. project-exposition (packaging as WAR, and I added the spring-boot-maven-plugin here. This module have the main class with @SpringBootConfiguration annotation)
4. project-infrastructure (packaging as JAR)

When I tried to run the application from project exposition I got the error :

```
Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
```

So I tried to add tomcat dependency

```
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
```

It works but the application runs and stops automatically with "Process finished with exit code 0"

I tried to add also in my application.yml

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: none
```

The app stops automatically after run again.

*for my purpose, I want to build a backend/frontend(angular) app, and deploy it on aws.*

Comment: Why is/must be `project-exposition` of type=war? (if there *is a reason* /yes:, then please refer to [Traditional Deployment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.traditional-deployment); if no: make it `jar`!;)

Comment: No reason, I just thought I have to make it war beause it contains the web application (Controllers...), I tried now with jar packaging, still have the same error